# Commissionaire in American English?

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english

As I understand it a "commissionaire" is only used in British English (or so says the dictionary), but then what is the American English alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically people use [**Doorman**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/doorman)

> a usually uniformed attendant at the door of a building (as a hotel or
>   apartment building)

Comment: And the [British definition of doorman](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/doorman): *a man such as a porter, bouncer, or janitor who is on duty at the entrance to a large building,* is incorrect in the U.S.:  bouncers and porters are not doormen (*janitor* means something different in England as well, so I can't comment on that one).

Answer (score 2):

As in [MacMillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/commissionaire) the alternatives are :

> [**bellboy**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/bellboy#bellboy__1) :  a man whose job is to carry people’s bags to their room in a hotel
>
> [**bellhop**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/bellhop#bellhop__1) : a person whose job is to carry people’s bags to their room in a hotel
>
> [**chambermaid**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/chambermaid#chambermaid__1) : a woman whose job is to clean the bedrooms in a hotel

and from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellhop),

> "A bellhop (North America) or hotel porter (international) is a hotel porter, who helps patrons with their luggage while checking in or out. Bellhops often wear a uniform (see bell-boy hat), like certain other page boys or doormen. This occupation is also called bellman and bellboy."

Comment: In the U.S., *chambermaids* and *doormen* are completely different.